# SecurityGroupPolicy not applied to DaemonSet

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

In my EKS cluster, I have a deployment and a daemonset.

The following SGP binds my deployment's pods to a couple of SecurityGroups I need:

```
apiVersion: vpcresources.k8s.aws/v1beta1
kind: SecurityGroupPolicy
metadata:
  name: efs-csi-controller
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: efs-csi-controller
  securityGroups:
    groupIds:
      - sg-11111111111111111
      - sg-22222222222222222
```

That works. But I need another set of pods to have the same security groups attached, as well.
This time it's a DaemonSet, though.

My 2nd SGP has a different name and selector:

```
podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: efs-csi-node
```

The problem is: the SGP doesn't seem to have an effect on my DaemonSet!
The `vpc.amazonaws.com/pod-eni` isn't applied, and I don't see any relevant message in the pods k8s events.
That behaviour doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.
Is there any limitation on SGP applied to DaemonSet, or am I missing something else?